# Laravel 5.3. Certain word causes method not found exception when posted

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I encountered laravel `method not found exception` while trying to post this sentence to controller

**5-6. It's ___ that penicillin, a ____ for various infections, was discovered by accident after some mold grew in a laboratory dish.**

I tried removing parts of the sentence and found out that whenever the word **"penicillin"** included, the error shows up.

What could be causing this issue ?

Here is code of my form. Im using tinymce plugin with laravel 5.3

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{url('question/essay/insert') }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">

              <div class="{{ $errors->has('question') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                  <label for="question" class="control-label">Question</label>
                  <textarea maxlength="50000" rows="10" id="question" type="text-area" class="form-control" name="question" value="{{ old('question') }}" required autofocus> {{ old('question') }} </textarea>

                  @if ($errors->has('question'))
                     <span class="help-block">
                       <strong>{{ $errors->first('question') }}</strong>
                     </span>
                  @endif

            </div>
            <div class="spacer-s"></div>
          </div>
       </div>

       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
             <div class="action-wrapper">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
             </div>
           </div>
       </div>
</form>
```

Code for my routing

```
Route::post('question/essay/insert','QuestionsController@insertEssayQuestion')->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: Seems it might be the apostrophe in " it's " .   Are you escaping that character?  Have you tried "it is" instead?

Comment: Hi, @glenviods, I believe, the error you have encountered is not due to the data you are posting, but due to the URL you are using in your `form` action attribute. Can you check in your routes if the URL is correct or maybe also include your routes code in the question?

Comment: Hi. Regarding aphostrophe, it went through just fine, i had tested it. Regarding the URL, no issue too. Every other word in that sentence is posted just fine. If i try to just post the word penicillin or include word penicillin in the sentence, then the method not found exception shows up

Comment: I have included route code in the question per your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

if you post to update route you need add _method input to your form.

```
@method('put')
```

Comment: Hi, I've put method post inside my form tag. And use Route::post to handle the request. Posting that sentence without the word penicillin is fine. It throws the error whenever i include penicillin